# App Engine: How to configure app.yaml for a flask app? Error: index.html not found

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, app.yaml

I have built a Flask app using Python 3.7. The setup works locally. When uploaded to GAE, I get an Internal Server Error. The GAE dashboard says `index.html` not found. Is this issue related to the `app.yaml` file?

My project structure is as follows:

```
root/
|-app.yaml
|-requirements.txt
|-main.py
|-other model files that feed into main.py
|-templates/
    |-index.html
    |-index2.html
    |-js
    |-css
    |-images
```

### app.yaml

```
    runtime: python37

    # [START handlers]
    handlers:
    - url: /.*
      script: auto

    - url: /index.html
      static_files: templates/index.html
      upload: Templates/index.html

    - url: /templates
      static_dir: Templates

    - url: /(.*\.(css|js|png|jpg))
      static_files: templates/\1
      upload: templates/(.*)
    # [END handlers]
```

Comment: Side note: the `app.yaml` patterns are case-sensitive and you're using both `Templates` and `templates` in your post. Granted, your IDE image shows it's just the post content.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I believe this was part of the problem.its now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Engine [`handlers` element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) documentation states:

> Patterns are evaluated in the order they appear in the `app.yaml` file, from top to bottom. The first mapping whose pattern matches the URL is the one used to handle the request.

- Put the catch-all handler at the end.
- The `templates` directory does not need to be added to the URL handlers.
- The `templates` directory should be lower case as a matter of convention. In addition, in the event that URL handlers do need to reference `templates`, the `app.yaml` patterns are case sensitive (as mentioned by [Dan Cornilescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4495081/dan-cornilescu)), and using lowercase will help avoid mismatches.
- The standard setup is to create a separate `static` (and/or `assets`) directory next to the `templates` directory. The `static` directory would contain files such as Javascript, CSS, and images.

### Project Structure

```
root/
|-app.yaml
|-requirements.txt
|-main.py
|-other model files that feed into main.py
|-static/
    |-js
    |-css
    |-images
|-templates/
    |-index.html
    |-index2.html
```

### app.yaml

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried that but still got the same error. Here is the screenshot of the debugger if that helps.
https://imgur.com/Ec0Yzbi

Comment: @SangyH Answer updated with standard project setup. An explicit URL handler for the Flask templates is not required.

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked. I first updated to the standard project setup. I still had the index.html not found issue. I then saw  Dan Cornilescu's comment on concerns with Templates vs templates. I then started over and created a new app, this time with the folder called templates, and it finally worked.

Comment: I’d suggest to also include the behavior about the capitalization of “templates” as a side note in this answer. It’s documented by @DanCornilescu as a comment in the original post.

Comment: @JKleinne Thanks for the note. Answer updated to include DanCornilescu's note on the lowercase `templates` folder due to `app.yaml` case sensitivity.